# Swagger and Date

Tags: javascript, json, rest, date, swagger

I'm new to swagger and writing my first spec. I've found following swagger "date" types*:

```
------------------------------------------------
| Common name        |  Swagger spec 1.2       |
------------------------------------------------
| string             |  string                 |
------------------------------------------------
| date               | string, date            |
------------------------------------------------
| dateTime           | string, date-time       |
------------------------------------------------
```

Now my timestamp looks like `2014-12-09T13:06:08.260+0000` is this even a Date? It doens't look like the date javascript `new Date();` returns. I also haven't found a date type in the [json specification](http://json.org/).

Which type and format should i take, will it be better to take string instead of a date??

*: note this table is the short version from the [swager wiki](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Datatypes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`2014-12-09T13:06:08.260+0000` is a variation of [ISO8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) date and time standard. JavaScript `Date` function can easily parse this format and `Date` has `toISOString()` method to produce strings in this format. The only thing is that letter *"Z"* is usually used to denote GMT/UTC time zone instead of *"+0000"*. But `Date` can parse it like that too.

Comment: so it's a date or a date-time?

Comment: @MemLeak it's date-time